# How can I execute an INSERT INTO statement that is saved to a string in cursor.execute() in Python when loading Data to a SQL Database?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

When loading data to an SQL Database using Python, I can use the following code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE [Test Table] ([Column 1] VARCHAR(10), [Column 2] VARCHAR(10), [Column 3] VARCHAR(10))")
for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO [Test Table] ([Column 1], [Column 2], [Column 3]) VALUES(?,?,?)", row._1, row._2, row._3)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Since I have to do many uploads, I wrote a script that generates the SQL statements as strings. The code then looks something like this:

```
create_string = "CREATE TABLE [Test Table] ([Column 1] VARCHAR(10), [Column 2] VARCHAR(10), [Column 3] VARCHAR(10))"
insert_string = "\'INSERT INTO [Test Table] ([Column 1], [Column 2], [Column 3]) VALUES(?,?,?)\', row._1, row._2, row._3"

data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
cursor.execute(create_string)
for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute(exec(insert_string))  #Error
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

The insert into statement does not work, and I don't know how to cast the string correctly. I have tried using the string itself, ast.literal_eval, eval, and exec.

Comment: Why don't you use `to_sql`? What you try to do is the *exact* opposite of how `cursor.execute` works. The whole point of using parameterized queries is to *avoid* passing values in the query string.

Comment: Executing INSERTs one by one like this is far slower than what `to_sql` would do, especially if you use `chunksize` to batch requests and `fast_executemany` when creating the connection.

Comment: Fair enough. ```to_sql``` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I should have used `to_sql`.